# Change Child Node Values by inserting parent nodes iterative

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

root = xml.Element('XmlToTs')
Eit = xml.Element('Eit')
root.append(Eit)


xml.SubElement(Eit, "Pid").text = "18"
Event = xml.Element("Event")
xml.SubElement(Event, "EventId").text = "12677" 
Short = xml.SubElement(Event, "ShortEventDescriptor")
xml.SubElement(Short, "Iso639LanguageCode").text = "deu" 
xml.SubElement(Short, "EventName").text = "Talk am Teich" 
xml.SubElement(Short, "Text").text = "Heute wird mit den Enten getalked" 

EID=12500
Eit.append(Event)
Eit.append(Event)
Eit.append(Event)
for EventId in Eit.iter('EventId'):
    EventId.text = str(EID)
    EID=EID+1
```

I want to have multiple "Event" Nodes with the default childs. After that i want to iterate through all and modify their child text´s.

But currently the iter loop gives all EventIds the 12502

Thanks Kristian

Answer (score 1):

You create **one** instance of your Event element when you call `Event = xml.Element("Event")`.
By passing this instance to the `.append()` method and calling it (in your case three times) ElementTree appends three EventId-Elments, but actually there is only **one** EventId-Element in the memory.
You can check this out with these lines:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

root = xml.Element('XmlToTs')
Eit = xml.Element('Eit')
root.append(Eit)

xml.SubElement(Eit, "Pid").text = "18"

Event = xml.Element("Event")
xml.SubElement(Event, "EventId").text = "12677"
Short = xml.SubElement(Event, "ShortEventDescriptor")
xml.SubElement(Short, "Iso639LanguageCode").text = "deu" 
xml.SubElement(Short, "EventName").text = "Talk am Teich" 
xml.SubElement(Short, "Text").text = "Heute wird mit den Enten getalked" 

Eit.append(Event)
Eit.append(Event)
Eit.append(Event)

for EventId in Eit.iter('EventId'):
    print(EventId)
```

The output is something like this:

```
<ELment 'EventId' at 0x17ee170>
<ELment 'EventId' at 0x17ee170>
<ELment 'EventId' at 0x17ee170>
```

As you can see **all** EventId-Elements have the **same** memory adders!

When you iterate with the `.iter()` method through all EventId-Tags  ElmentTree can found in your XML-Code, in every iteration you are accessing the **same** object i.e. the **same** EventId-Tag.
This was the reason why all text attributes of each EventId-Element were assigned to the same number 12502; 12500 was incremented twice.

To cut a long story short, you need to create multiple EventId instances; for instance in a for loop:

```
for _ in range(3):
    Event = xml.Element("Event")

    xml.SubElement(Event, "EventId").text = "12677"

    Short = xml.SubElement(Event, "ShortEventDescriptor")

    xml.SubElement(Short, "Iso639LanguageCode").text = "deu" 
    xml.SubElement(Short, "EventName").text = "Talk am Teich" 
    xml.SubElement(Short, "Text").text = "Heute wird mit den Enten getalked" 

    Eit.append(Event)
```

After that you can run your code...

```
EID=12500

for EventId in Eit.iter('EventId'):
    EventId.text= str(EID)
    EID += 1
```

... and it works perfectly! :)

---

The full source code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
from xml.dom import minidom

root = xml.Element('XmlToTs')
Eit = xml.Element('Eit')
root.append(Eit)


xml.SubElement(Eit, "Pid").text = "18"

for _ in range(3):
    Event = xml.Element("Event")

    xml.SubElement(Event, "EventId").text = "12677"

    Short = xml.SubElement(Event, "ShortEventDescriptor")

    xml.SubElement(Short, "Iso639LanguageCode").text = "deu" 
    xml.SubElement(Short, "EventName").text = "Talk am Teich" 
    xml.SubElement(Short, "Text").text = "Heute wird mit den Enten getalked" 


    Eit.append(Event)


EID=12500

for EventId in Eit.iter('EventId'):
    EventId.text= str(EID)
    EID += 1


#print the generated XML code

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = xml.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent=" ")

print(prettify(Eit))
```